# HTTP Status 400 Only in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internet-explorer, firefox

I´m developing a WebApp with SpringMVC. So far the WebApp works fine. I have a .jsp file which represents my view. The user could see the view (In Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc.) But when the user submits a form on the view it only works in IE and NOT in Chrome and Firefox!

This is my .jsp File:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

    ...

<body>

    <form:form id="circle_form" modelAttribute="circleUpModel"
        method="POST" action="">

        ...

        <input type="button" onclick="javascript:submitForm()"
            value="Start Circle Up">

    </form:form>

    <div id="progressbar">
        <div class="progress-label">Loading...</div>
    </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ...

    function submitForm() {
        if (checkIfPdf() && checkSettings()) {
            $("#circle_form").submit();
            setTimeout(progress, 100);
        }
    }

    ...
</script>
</html>
```

And this is the related POST Method of the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CircleUp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView circleUpPost(HttpServletRequest _request, Model _model, @ModelAttribute("circleUpModel") CircleUpModel _circleUpModel) {

        ...
    }
```

When Debugging it seems that the POST Method is not even called! And I get the Error:

HTTP Status 400 - The request send by the client was syntactically incorrect.

I also looked into the "network analysis" of Firebug. Firebug could find the POST Method but it is marked as read. Because I´m not familiar with the network analysis of Firebug I cannot gain any informations of it.

UPDATE

I checked the field names and could not find a mistake! Maybe I have overlooked something...

This is my form of the .jsp File:

```
    <form:input path="file" id="upload" type="file" />

    <form:checkbox path="mergeSameTickmarks" checked="true" />
    <br />
    <form:checkbox path="deleteHighlights" checked="true" />
    <br />
    <form:checkbox path="generateFigureLog" checked="true" />
    <br />
    <div id="accordion">
        <div>
            <form:input path="tickmarkBorderWidth" id="tickmarkBorderWidth"
                type="text" value="0.7" class="borderWidth" />
            <br />

            <form:checkbox path="tickmarkAlwaysUpperCase"
                id="tickmarkAlwaysUpperCase" checked="true" name="Test" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <form:input path="circleBorderWidth" id="circleBorderWidth"
                type="text" value="0.7" class="borderWidth" />
            <br />

            <form:input path="customizeCircleUp" id="customizeCircleUp"
                type="text" value="0.0" />
            <br />

            <form:input path="customizeCircleDown" id="customizeCircleDown"
                type="text" value="0.0" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <form:input path="lineBorderWidth" id="lineBorderWidth" type="text"
                value="0.7" class="borderWidth" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <form:input path="gapLeft" id="gapLeft" type="text" value="20"
                class="gaps" />
            <br />

            <form:input path="gapRight" id="gapRight" type="text" value="50"
                class="gaps" />
            <br />

            <form:input path="maxGap" id="maxGap" type="text" value="50" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:submitForm()"
        value="Start Circle Up">

</form:form>
```

And this is my Model:

```
public class CircleUpModel {

        // File
        private File    file;

        // FileName
        private String  fileName;

        private boolean mergeSameTickmarks;
        private boolean deleteHighlights;
        private boolean generateFigureLog;

        // Settings
        private double  circleBorderWidth;
        private double  tickmarkBorderWidth;
        private double  lineBorderWidth;

        private double  customizeCircleUp;
        private double  customizeCircleDown;

        private int     gapLeft;
        private int     gapRight;
        private int     maxGap;

        private boolean tickmarkAlwaysUpperCase;

        public File getFile() {
            return file;
        }

        public void setFile(File file) {
            this.file = file;
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public boolean isMergeSameTickmarks() {
            return mergeSameTickmarks;
        }

        public void setMergeSameTickmarks(boolean mergeSameTickmarks) {
            this.mergeSameTickmarks = mergeSameTickmarks;
        }

        public boolean isDeleteHighlights() {
            return deleteHighlights;
        }

        public void setDeleteHighlights(boolean deleteHighlights) {
            this.deleteHighlights = deleteHighlights;
        }

        public boolean isGenerateFigureLog() {
            return generateFigureLog;
        }

        public void setGenerateFigureLog(boolean generateFigureLog) {
            this.generateFigureLog = generateFigureLog;
        }

        public double getCircleBorderWidth() {
            return circleBorderWidth;
        }

        public void setCircleBorderWidth(double circleBorderWidth) {
            this.circleBorderWidth = circleBorderWidth;
        }

        public double getTickmarkBorderWidth() {
            return tickmarkBorderWidth;
        }

        public void setTickmarkBorderWidth(double tickmarkBorderWidth) {
            this.tickmarkBorderWidth = tickmarkBorderWidth;
        }

        public double getLineBorderWidth() {
            return lineBorderWidth;
        }

        public void setLineBorderWidth(double lineBorderWidth) {
            this.lineBorderWidth = lineBorderWidth;
        }

        public double getCustomizeCircleUp() {
            return customizeCircleUp;
        }

        public void setCustomizeCircleUp(double customizeCircleUp) {
            this.customizeCircleUp = customizeCircleUp;
        }

        public double getCustomizeCircleDown() {
            return customizeCircleDown;
        }

        public void setCustomizeCircleDown(double customizeCircleDown) {
            this.customizeCircleDown = customizeCircleDown;
        }

        public boolean isTickmarkAlwaysUpperCase() {
            return tickmarkAlwaysUpperCase;
        }

        public void setTickmarkAlwaysUpperCase(boolean tickmarkAlwaysUpperCase) {
            this.tickmarkAlwaysUpperCase = tickmarkAlwaysUpperCase;
        }

        public int getGapLeft() {
            return gapLeft;
        }

        public void setGapLeft(int gapLeft) {
            this.gapLeft = gapLeft;
        }

        public int getGapRight() {
            return gapRight;
        }

        public void setGapRight(int gapRight) {
            this.gapRight = gapRight;
        }

        public int getMaxGap() {
            return maxGap;
        }

        public void setMaxGap(int maxGap) {
            this.maxGap = maxGap;
        }

    }
```

UPDATE 19.10.2017

After adding `enctype='multipart/form-data` to my form the POST Method of my Controller is (finally)called! But unfortunately the model is empty and thus the process throws a NullPointer Exception.

This is my form right now:

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="circleUpModel" id="circle_form"  method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <%
        out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_LBL_INPUT_FILE));
    %>
    <form:input path="file" id="upload" type="file" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <%
        out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_LBL_MERGE_TICKMARKS));
    %>
    <form:checkbox path="mergeSameTickmarks" checked="true" />
    <br />
    <%
        out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_LBL_DELETE_HIGHLIGHTS));
    %>
    <form:checkbox path="deleteHighlights" checked="true" />
    <br />
    <%
        out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_LBL_GENERATE_FIGURELOG));
    %>
    <form:checkbox path="generateFigureLog" checked="true" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="accordion">
        <h4>
            <%
                out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_SETTINGS_TICKMARK));
            %>
        </h4>
        <div>
            <%
                out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_SETTINGS_TICKMARK_ALWAYS_UPPER));
            %>
            <form:checkbox path="tickmarkAlwaysUpperCase"
                id="tickmarkAlwaysUpperCase" checked="true" name="Test" />
        </div>

        <h4>
            <%
                out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_SETTINGS_CIRCLE));
            %>
        </h4>
        <div>
            <%
                out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_SETTINGS_CIRCLE_WIDTH));
            %>
            <form:input path="circleBorderWidth" id="circleBorderWidth"
                type="text" value="0.7" class="borderWidth" />
            <br />

            <%
                out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_SETTINGS_CIRCLE_UP));
            %>
            <form:input path="customizeCircleUp" id="customizeCircleUp"
                type="text" value="0.0" />
            <br />

            <%
                out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_SETTINGS_CIRCLE_DOWN));
            %>
            <form:input path="customizeCircleDown" id="customizeCircleDown"
                type="text" value="0.0" />
        </div>

        <h4>Other</h4>
        <div>
            <%
                out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_SETTINGS_GAP_LEFT));
            %>
            <form:input path="gapLeft" id="gapLeft" type="text" value="0"
                class="gaps" />
            <br />

            <%
                out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_SETTINGS_GAP_RIGHT));
            %>
            <form:input path="gapRight" id="gapRight" type="text" value="0"
                class="gaps" />
            <br />

            <%
                out.println(bundle.getString(Constants.VIEW_CIRCLEUP_SETTINGS_MAX_GAP));
            %>
            <form:input path="maxGap" id="maxGap" type="text" value="50" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:submitForm()"
        value="Start Circle Up">

</form:form>
```

To make my problem more understandable: I debugged the POST Method of my Controller and the _circleUpModel in the argument only has default values and nulls as variables (Instead I entered some values in my form on my .jsp)

[image: Bug]

Maybe I should implement a multipartResolver? I have read something about it but when I implemented one by adding a Bean in my ContextConfig with:

```
     @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
 public MultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
 CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
 resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");

 resolver.setMaxUploadSize(10 * 1024 * 1024);

 return resolver;
 }
```

And than add it to my controller like:

```
     @InitBinder
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder _dataBinder) {
 Object target = _dataBinder.getTarget();
 if (target == null) {
 return;
 }
 if (target.getClass() == CircleUpModel.class) {
 // Register to handle the conversion between the multipart object and byte array.
 _dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(byte [].class, new ByteArrayMultipartFileEditor());
 }
 }
```

The POST Method will even not be called !!

Comment: Congrats, since its working in IE. Please check if the field names in java and html form are correct. Also ensure that you have assigned correct data to those fields in java especially boolean fields if any.

Comment: @Valath: I have looked at the field names and I could not find any mistake. I posted my form and Model!

Comment: Try to remove the checkbox to see if this one cause your problem

Comment: @AtimeneNazim: I tried it and it doesn´t work :(

Comment: add this to the form that upload file `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @AtimeneNazim Now nothing does work! Even the IE does not work. But it is an other Error. It says: "The page could not be loaded"!

Comment: @AtimeneNazim: I deleted some unused stuff and now when I add 'enctype="multipart/form-data' to my form in the POST method of my controller all entrys of the form are empty. Obvisiouly the form isn´t saved. Do you have an idea?

Comment: check in the browser if this one send your form ! do you get some stack ? please edit your post and add all the form from the `<form:form> `to `</form:from>`